# jQuery delegate and preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following preventDefault() implementation is not working.

I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. I can see 'ev' in the debugger and it looks like a fully fledged Event.

I am trying to break down code for another thing I am debugging.

Html:

```
<body>
<a data-action="custom-modal" href="test_modal_content1.html">Test 1</a>
<a data-action="custom-modal" href="test_modal_content2.html">Test 2</a>
<div class="modal modal-6 fade" id="modal-form" role="dialog" arialabelledby="modalFormLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
function TestModal() {}

TestModal.prototype.toggleModal = function () {
  $('body').delegate('a[data-action=custom-modal]', 'click', function (ev) {
    $(ev).preventDefault();
  });
};

var testModal = new TestModal();
testModal.toggleModal();
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrobens/dLy5s7b8/).

Thanks

Comment: Review the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
 ev.preventDefault();
```

instead of

```
 $(ev).preventDefault();
```